# Android background JSON value monitoring service, Notification on value changed and greater. What is the best approach?

Tags: android, json, notifications, alarmmanager, background-service

I want to create a service in android that periodically checks a JSON value and if that value has changed and is greater it should trigger a notification. I want to know whats the best way to do this and how the values are saved and compared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have local database, you can check size of the local database table and adequate table that you recieve from JSON.